# what is the probability of choosing given $n$ distinct people out of $m$ distinct people in a particular order

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I initially thought it should be $(1-p)^{(m-n)}(p^n)$ where $p=(1/m)$ but i was not convinced as after choosing one people the probability of choosing next people will be different . What am I missing ? Thanks!

Comment: What precisely do you mean by choosing the people in a particular order? How does the choosing look?

Comment: n people are already decided in order like the first people should be a1 second should be a2 (first can not be a2), i need  the probablity of choosing this  n people out of total m people in this order

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in a comment the question is about probability that upon ordering of $m$ people $n$ of them will be numbered in a prescribed way.

The corresponding probability is:
$$\frac {(m-n)!}{m!}.
$$

Here the numerator counts the number of ways to arrange the rest $m-n$ people, and the denominator counts the overall number of ways to order $m $ people.